# Create criteria query with counting summ of different columns

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have got a problem: how can i make criteria query if i need to add values of two different columns? In SQL it will seems such way: `SELECT START_TIME + DURATION FROM TEST_RESULTS;` How can i make this with the help of criteria?

Comment: Can you provide a demo of what you're trying to achieve at `sqlfiddle` http://sqlfiddle.com  ? And please, make your question more clearer. Its very hard to understand this wy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is explained here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1001549

You can use:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.sqlProjection("this_.START_TIME + _this.DURATION as custom_sum", new String[] {"custom_sum"}, new Type[]{org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.INSTANCE}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i v got a next error 
"INTEGER cannot be resolved or is not a 
 field"

Comment: You can use org.hibernate.type.LongType.INSTANCE *OR* org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.INSTANCE